# Доступ к mysql через php скрипт в linux

Tags: php, linux, веб-программирование, phpmyadmin

Решил наконец освоить что-то новое, перешел на linux. Перенёс файлы проекта на ноутбук, развернул xampp, открываю проект, и вижу, что данные из таблиц не подгружаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код вот, в файле index.php:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первое, что сделал:

```
sudo chmod +x index.php
```

К результату не привело. Остальные скрипты работают. При входе на страницу запускается php-скрипт, который создает необходимые базы данных и таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но, сам index.php не исполняется.

P.S.: система kubuntu, настройки phpmyadmin не менял (стандартные в xampp - login: 'root', pwd: '')

UPD: пока писал, решил проверить внутренности таблиц и они пустые.

Для простоты, датасет был набросан в таблицы csv, а потом импорт в БД, и импорта нет. На windows все в порядке, что делать на linux - пока не разобрался

UPD 2: функция импорта из CSV

```
function importFromCSV($link, $fileName, $tableName) {
    $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '../../htdocs/cifroBreak/php/TABLES/".$fileName."'
            INTO TABLE ".$tableName." 
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
            ENCLOSED BY '\"'";

    mysqli_query($link, $sql);
}
```

Коннект:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$dbname = 'graduate_work';

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
```

Часть index-кода:

```
<select name="region" class="reg">
    <!-- region -->
    <option value="%">Выберите регион</option>
    <?php
        mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT region FROM citys";
        $result_select = mysqli_query($conn, $sql, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
        while($object = mysqli_fetch_object($result_select)){
            echo "<option value = '$object->region' > $object->region </option>";}
    ?>
 </select>
```

Comment: *Код вот, в файле index.php:* А просто текстом дать религия не позволила? Замените фотографию на текст. Покажите инициализацию переменных `$conn` и `$dbname`. Добавьте в код проверки на ошибку при соединении и при запросе, выведите и покажите сообщение об ошибке. Покажите DDL таблицы `citys`.

Comment: Ошибок нет. В UPD написал, что данные просто не импортируются из CSV

Comment: new mysqli()....

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось, что XAMPP mySQL в Linux и Windows работают как-то по разному. 
При импорте некоторых строк таблицы, в нескольких ячейках длинна строки была выше допустимой, однако Windows это исключение не обработал, и записывал данные как есть, а Linux ругался, на то, что я пытаюсь записать строку в 67 символов, в ячейку VARCHAR(40).